# REGEX good start but need some excluding

Tags: regex

I have that regex

```
\{([^{}]|(?R))*\}
```

that matches fine the outermost brackets content

```
foo{
    subfoo{
       "foofoofoo..."
    }
}foo

//Matches :
//   {
//   subfoo{
//      "foofoofoo..."
//   } 
//}
```

But I need to add some exclusion to that:

- Bypass every brackets that is located into simple or double quotes
- Don't match if the closing bracket is followed by \s*; (semicolon with any white space between)

So the following text should give:

```
foo{
   subfoo{
      "foofoofoo... { "
   }
}foo

//Matches :
//   {
//   subfoo{
//      "foofoofoo... { "
//   } 
//}
```

and

```
foo{foofoofoo} ;

//Matches nothing
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: #2 can be easily achieved with negative assertion `... \}(?!\s+)`; meanwhile #1 I'm not sure can be made with regexp (especially if we want ignore escaped quotes and say single quote mark inside of double-quoted string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your pattern to its unrolled version (that is more efficient):

```
\{[^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*+\}
```

Then, following the same idea, you can easily describe parts into quotes:

```
\{[^{}"]*+(?:"[^"]*"[^{}"]*|(?R)[^{}"]*)*+\}
```

*(same thing to include single quotes too, exclude the single quote from the negated character classes and add a branch that describes the quoted part)*

You can also take escaped quotes in account:

```
\{[^{}"]*+(?:"[^"\\]*+(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*+"[^{}"]*|(?R)[^{}"]*)*+\}
```

If you don't want closing curly brackets to be followed by a `;` add a negative lookahead as suggested. `(?!\s+;)` or `(?!\s*;)` depending of what you want. But if you only want to target the outermost closing bracket, you have to check if you are in a recursion or not before, using a conditional statement `(?(condition)then|else)` : `(?(R)|(?!\s+;))` or `(?(R)|(?!\s*;))`

Comment: I barely know the basics of REGEXP.. I tried your examples on https://regex101.com/ but they returned an error " ( Incomplete group structure "

Comment: @LePioo: It was a typo, depending of what you want: `\{([^{}]*+(?:(?R)[^{}]*)*+)\}` to have a capture inside brackets or the edited version if you don't need it. Same thing for the other patterns.

Comment: thank you so much !
(I repost here the REGEXP on the demo link)
\{[^{}"']*+(?:"[^"\\]*+(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*+"[^{}"']*|'[^'\\]*+(?s:\\.[^'\\]*)*+'[^{}"']|(?R)[^{}"]*)*+\}(?(R)|(?!\s*;))

Comment: one more question: do you know if this REGEX can be interpreted on javascript , python or even C# ?

Comment: @LePioo: Python, only with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Javascript, perhaps something is possible using [XRegExp.matchRecursive()](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive), but there is no conditional feature. .net languages, possible but you have to rewrite the pattern to use the *balancing groups* instead of the recursion.